# Install Ansible on Vagrant guest from local machine

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I'm using Vagrant and the ansible_local provisioner. Is there a way to specify where Ansible will be downloaded from? [install_mode](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_local.html#install_mode) only selects how to install Ansible, not from where.

*EDIT
With "where" I mean specify the download location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you could specify the download source location. Either APT, RPM, or pip installation commands are hardcoded in Vagrant. For example:

- [ansible_install.rb](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/provisioners/ansible/cap/guest/debian/ansible_install.rb#L32) (for Debian):

  ```
      def self.ansible_apt_install(machine)

      // skipped

        machine.communicate.sudo install_backports_if_wheezy_release
        machine.communicate.sudo "apt-get update -y -qq"
        machine.communicate.sudo "apt-get install -y -qq ansible"
      end

      def self.pip_setup(machine)
        machine.communicate.sudo "apt-get update -y -qq"
        machine.communicate.sudo "apt-get install -y -qq build-essential curl git libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev"
        Pip::get_pip machine
      end
  ```
- [pip.rb](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/9c299a2a357fcf87f356bb9d56e18a037a53d138/plugins/provisioners/ansible/cap/guest/pip/pip.rb#L16) (when using `:pip`):

  ```
      machine.communicate.sudo "pip install #{upgrade_arg}#{package}#{version_arg}"
  ```

---

That said, if you want to avoid downloading on each `vagrant up`, you could:

- use a proxy for APT or yum. For example [Apt-Cacher](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Apt-Cacher-Server) (you'd need to modify the configuration with shell provisioning to point to the proxy);
- use a Vagrant plugin like [vagrant-cachier](https://github.com/fgrehm/vagrant-cachier) (doesn't work for pip and generally is unreliable and not maintained);
- use the shell provisioner to download and install Ansible using the command you want;
- probably the best: use [Vagrant Packer](https://www.packer.io/intro/getting-started/vagrant.html) to create your customised box image with the required packages (i.e. Ansible) already installed.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about Vagrant Packer, will check it out.